# Using http.delete in Angular and .Net MVC 5 / Web API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, http-delete

**Using WebApi & MVC 5 and

*AngularJS v1.3.4***

I have an API setup that has a `FavoritesRepository` & `IFavoritesRepository` & Ninject. This part is ok, I can retrieve Favorites by UserId or SearchId. My favorites list is an API built around a `Search.cs` model:

```
namespace RenderLib.Models
{
  public class Search
  {
    public int SearchId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(128), Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2080), Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In my DataLayer Directory I have the `FavoritesRepository` & `IFavoritesRepository` with the following Add & Delete method.
(The Add method works with Angular just fine):

**/DataLayer/IFavoritesRepository.cs**

```
namespace RenderLib.DataLayer
{
  public interface IFavoritesRepository
  {
    IQueryable<Search> GetFavoritesByUserId(string id);
    IQueryable<Search> GetFavoriteBySearchId(int id);

    bool Save();
    bool AddFavorite(Search newSearch);
    bool DelFavorite(int id);
  }
}
```

**/DataLayer/FavoritesRepository.cs**

```
namespace RenderLib.DataLayer
{
  public class FavoritesRepository : IFavoritesRepository
  {
    RenderLibContext _ctx;
    public FavoritesRepository(RenderLibContext ctx)
    {
      _ctx = ctx;
    }


    public IQueryable<Search> GetFavoritesByUserId(string id)
    {
      return _ctx.Search.Where(s => s.UserId == id);
    }

    public IQueryable<Search> GetFavoriteBySearchId(int id)
    {
      return _ctx.Search.Where(s => s.SearchId == id);
    }


    public bool Save()
    {
      try
      {
        return _ctx.SaveChanges() > 0;
      }
      catch
      {
        // TODO log this error
        return false;
      }
    }

    public bool AddFavorite(Search newFavorite)
    {
      _ctx.Search.Add(newFavorite);
      return true;
    }

    public bool DelFavorite(int id)
    {
      var search = _ctx.Search;
      search.Remove(search.SingleOrDefault(s => s.SearchId == id));
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have a WebAPI Controller where the POST Method already adds a new Favorite. I have copied over the POST and changed it to delete and attempted trying to get it to work, but my real problem is figuring out what to do with Angular

**/Controllers/Api/FavoritesController.cs**

```
public class FavoritesController : ApiController
{
    private IFavoritesRepository _favRepo;
    public FavoritesController(IFavoritesRepository favRepo)
    {
        _favRepo = favRepo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Search> Get()
    {
        var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        IQueryable<Search> results; 
        results = _favRepo.GetFavoritesByUserId(id);

        var favorites = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.UserId == id);

        return favorites;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Search newFavorite)
    {
        if (newFavorite.Created == null)
        {
            newFavorite.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        if (_favRepo.AddFavorite(newFavorite) && _favRepo.Save())
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, newFavorite);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(Search id)
    {
        if (_favRepo.DelFavorite(id) && _favRepo.Save())
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, id);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

On the Angular end we have the Index.cshtml page that is the root of the site and has within it a section of angular code. That section has two angular routes, one `"#/"` which load the following angular template/view: `favoritesView.html` & `newFavoiteView.html` which has the angular route `"#/newfavorite"`

**/ng-templates/favoritesView.html**
**Route: #/**

```
<a class="tiny button radius" href="#/newfavorite">Add</div>
<div class="small-12 column">
    <div class="favContent">
        <div class="search row" data-ng-repeat="s in vm.searches">
            <div class="favName small-10 column">
                <a href="{{s.searchString}}">{{s.name}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="small-2 column">
                <a href="" ng-click="vm.delete(s.searchId)">
                    <i class="fi-trash"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**/ng-templates/newFavoriteView.html**
**Route: #/newfavorite**

```
<div class="small-12 column"><h3>Saving Search</h3></div>
<div class="small-12 column">
    <form name="newFavoriteForm" novalidate ng-submit="vm.save()">
        <input name="userId" type="hidden" 
               ng-model="vm.newFavorite.userId" />
        <input name="searchString" type="hidden" 
               ng-model="vm.newFavorite.searchString" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" 
               ng-model="vm.newFavorite.name" autofocus/>
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="30" 
                  ng-model="vm.newFavorite.description"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" class="tiny button radius" value="Save" /> | 
        <a href="#/" class="tiny button radius">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Finally I have the Angular Modules and Controllers (Again, Everything is working except for the delete. I'm just not sure what I should be doing in my favoritesView.html and how it works with the controller. ALso is my WebApi controller and Repo setup correctly?

**Module & Controllers**
**/ng-modules/render-index.js**

```
angular
    .module("renderIndex", ["ngRoute","ngCookies"])
    .config(config)
    .controller("favoritesController", favoritesController)
    .controller("newFavoriteController", newFavoriteController);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/ng-templates/favoritesView.html",
            controller: "favoritesController",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        })
        .when("/newfavorite", {
            templateUrl: "/ng-templates/newFavoriteView.html",
            controller: "newFavoriteController",
            controllerAs: "vm"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
};

function favoritesController($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.searches = [];
    vm.isBusy = true;

    $http.get("/api/favorites")
        .success(function (result) {
            vm.searches = result;
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert('error/failed');
        })
        .then(function () {
            vm.isBusy = false;
        });

    vm.delete = function (searchId) {
        var url = "/api/favorites/" + searchId;
        $http.delete(url)
            .success(function (result) {
                var newFavorite = result.data;
                //TODO: merge with existing topics
                alert("Delete Successfull");
                removeFromArray(vm.searches, searchId);
            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("Your broken, go fix yourself!");
            })
            .then(function () {
                $window.location = "#/";
            });
    };
};

function removeFromArray(items, searchId) {
    var index;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].searchId == searchId) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index) {
        items.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

function newFavoriteController($http, $window, $cookies) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.newFavorite = {};
    vm.newFavorite.searchString = $cookies.currentSearch;
    vm.newFavorite.userId = $cookies.uId;
    vm.save = function () {
        $http.post("/api/favorites", vm.newFavorite)
            .success(function (result) {
                var newFavorite = result.data;
                //TODO: merge with existing topics
                alert("Thanks for your post");
            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("Your broken, go fix yourself!");
            })
            .then(function () {
                $window.location = "#/";
            });
    };
};
```

I have been thinking about this all night. This code came from a pluralisight video from Shawn Wildermuth and I changed it to work with `ControllerAs` and got rid of the scope and for some reason I just don't know exactly how to setup the delete. ANy help or a push in the right direction would be much appreciated. I've got it this far I can't let a delete action defeat me.

---

**ANSWER**
The above code has been updated with the working version. The idea was to remove the form on the `favoritesView.html` and just use an

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="vm.delete(s.searchId)">X</a>
```

To call the delete function. Omri not only helped me with the concept of how to get the parameter over to the function but also helped me write a function that would update the view to show the removed item. I am very thankful for his help. Please 1up his answer if you find this useful.

Comment: Something that worked for me: change `$http.delete("/api/favorites", vm.delFavorite)` to `$http["delete"]("/api/favorites", vm.delFavorite)`

Comment: By the way, I only use a URL without data, if you use data I think it needs to be sent as an object.

Comment: Yeah, as you could see I was copying from the Add/Post function, so maybe I should just be sending a parameter instead of an object, I'm really looking for some advice on the easiest way to do it. I'll look into your idea and keep researching but my problem is coming up with the whole final solution. Im not sure if Im just so tired or I just and missing a simple concept that has me blocked.

Comment: Yeah if you have an identifier for an object an `$http.delete(url)` where url contains the identifier should be the way to go.

Comment: The identifier is searchId. I was assuming I could pull that out of the view and pass it to the controller, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that. DO I pass an object or just the id? Any ideas of the syntax from the controller where we pass the objects into the view and repeat over them and how to get that id back into the delete method? I'm not sure of how to do that. I wish the tutorials I used would have had some insight into that. BUt they kind of left me hanging even well before the point I'm But I know Im very close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll sum this up as an answer since the comments are getting way too busy :)

Since you have `ng-model="vm.newFavorite.searchId"` in the view, you can get your searchId and you use it to append to the url:

```
vm.delete = function (searchId) {

    //API Controller will expect "/api/favorites/13" from an http delete

    var url = "/api/favorites/" + searchId;
    $http.delete(url)
        .success(function (result) {
            var newFavorite = result.data;
            //TODO: merge with existing topics
            alert("Delete Successfull");
            removeFromArray(vm.searches, searchId);
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert("Your broken, go fix yourself!");
        })
        .then(function () {
            $window.location = "#/";
        });
};
```

};

Notice that now the `Delete` function in your `FavoritesController` is now only expecting a `searchId` parameter, so you need to change the names either on the client or the server so they should match, and you definitely need to change the type of the variable in the server from `Search` to string or Guid I assume.

**EDIT**: After a chat discussion, we came to the conclusion to remove the form elements and have just a button and `ng-click` to the delete function.

Comment: Let me run with this. I'll update my source if I run into any snags.

Comment: I have updated the DelFavorite in the `FavoritesRepository.cs` and the `vm.delete()` function in the Controller. It is making more sense now. But where do I put the `searchId` in the form?

I should be able to get it from {{s.searchId}} but how do I pass that back into the vm.delete() function which passes it to the WebApi Controller?

Comment: @EricB You can modify it to be `ng-click="vm.delete({{s.searchId}});"` and then update the function to receive the parameter.

Comment: can you take a look at my view and my controller and tell me if I have the syntax right? I just updated it above

Comment: @EricB Your view seems fine, I updated the function in my answer, adjust yours to match.

Comment: my button is no good, it's refreshing the whole page, somehow the ng-click is not submitting the form. I'm assuming it because it's an a href and not a button? man I'm confused how to pass this searchId to the vm.delete() function..

Comment: @EricB Yeah you're right, I didn't notice. On my angular apps I don't use `href` at all, since you have `ng-click` and the angular routing. Change to `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: still not working. Wondering why I even need a form in the first place, Im not using the hidden input and it seems I should just be able to pass searchId to the controller. There is some type of issue with this setup. The value is not getting passed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71866/discussion-between-omri-aharon-and-eric-b).

Comment: @EricB Thanks for the credit at the end, kind words :)

Comment: If you want to circumvent that `WebApi` expects `/id`. then you need to state in the WebApi Controller Delete Action : `[FromUri] int searchId`